# Telegram bot location

Tags: python, bots, telegram, telegram-bot

Is it possible to find out a person location each time when user sends a message to bot. Or how can I find out the user's location? I would like to do this without sending the key position. Thanks

Comment: Maybe you need [this](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api/#location) , but that was a really easy search!

Answer (score 3):

No you can't get user locations without their permission unless you use `request_location` in your keyboard, then it will show a message and asks user for the permission.
https://core.telegram.org/bots/api/#keyboardbutton